# Convert the string of numbers into comma separated values

Tags: php

I want the string of numbers into comma separated values.

I have tried this:

```
$str = 12345;
$newStr = "'" . str_replace("",",", $str) . "'";
print_r($newStr);
```

expected output:- 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: https://eval.in/664071   something like this?

Comment: Ninad check the answers below. Thanks

Comment: people not responding to answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$str = 12345;
$arr= str_split($str); //will output in array
echo implode(',',$arr); //convert array to string with delimiter
```